# Operators and Functions

Tags: function, operators

Are operators faster than the functions or methods that offer the same functionality such as the append method or '+' to add elements to a list? Though the question isn't language specific, I still feel the need to mention that I am a beginner in python.

Comment: This is *extremely* language specific.

Comment: Operators can generally be regarded as functions. It's more of a syntactic difference. It'll depend on the language specifically though.

Comment: In functional programming, operators *are* functions. In Python specifically, operators mostly *invoke* functions. In other languages, operators may be overloadable by functions. In yet other languages, there may be no correlation.